# Q: Django crispy forms - change behavior depending url

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-crispy-forms

I don't know how to implement this with django crispy forms.

I have an interface with a URL like this:

`myurl.com/movements/new`

And I have a select in the form with the type of movement.

When there is not a type of movement explicitly assigned, just shows the select without any option selected.

[image: unselected]

When user access to form with an URL like `myurl.com/movements/income/`
I want this select to have by default the `income` option.

[image: income]

And so on with every possible option.

I know that I can use JavaScript for this, but I think that it would be better to have it on the back-end.

How can I achieve this on the back-end part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`models.py`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Income', 'Income'),
        ('Option2', 'Option2'),
        ('Option3', 'Option3'),
    )
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CHOICES)
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^new/(?P<option>[\w.@+-]+)/$',  # feel free to adjust the regex
        view=views.NewCreateView.as_view(),
        name='new'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^new/$',
        view=views.NewCreateView.as_view(),
        name='new'
    )
]
```

`views.py`:

```
class NewCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['choice']

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        if 'option' in self.kwargs:
            if any(self.kwargs['option'] in choice for choice in MyModel.CHOICES):
                form_kwargs['initial']['choice'] = self.kwargs['option']
        return form_kwargs
```

The initial selection of the drop-down list is only given if you visit the URL `new/` with a valid option like `new/Income`. Of course, you can adjust the URL according to your needs.

You could also override [`get_initial`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_initial) instead of `get_form_kwargs`.

Comment: Thank you! the `view` part is exactly what I needed